# Fast start/stop/restart of remote windows service

Tags: java, windows, powershell, command-line, windows-services

In some of our scripts we restart windows services on remote servers.

The actual service restarts in less than 2 seconds when we are connected to the server using Remote Desktop.

We have tested all of below:

1. psexec \\*server* net stop *service* - 
   Takes 2 seconds, but uses 20+ seconds to start PSEXESVC service up first
2. psservice \\*server* start *service* - takes 20 seconds
3. sc \\*server* start *service* - takes 20 seconds

So a total stop->start will take 40+ seconds. Going through XX servers bumps up script execution time to XX minutes.

How can we get a faster response on a start/stop using command line tools/Powershell/Java/ANT/etc ?

We want to start/stop remotely within the same time it takes to do it locally.

Comment: Do you have PowerShell Remoting enabled? If so, how does `Invoke-Command -ComputerName _server_ -ScriptBlock { Start-Service _service_ }` (from a PowerShell prompt) work?

Comment: `stop-service\start-service`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-service

Comment: In powershell as you want to restart a service, you can use `Restart-Service` instead of `Stop-Service` and `Start-Service`

Comment: I'm not on a windows box at the moment, but `Get-Service -Name Service -ComputerName Server | Restart-Service` might be all that's needed?

Comment: @JamesC. - One of these days, I'll get my brain wrapped around the pipeline... :)

Comment: Modified one of the scripts which takes around 12 minutes to execute. Using PS it executes in 4 minutes, so a significant improvement. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46455394/2048204 can some please answer this! Thank you